# Programmatically modify an image to replace detail with text?

Tags: image-processing

How would one programatically reproduce the following effect?
[image]
<sub>(source: [artext.co.uk](http://www.artext.co.uk/images/twofonts%20typography%20ascii%201.gif))</sub>

I'd like to automate the process if possible, but have some control over the output (IE, inverting the color pallet to produce a light background for dark images, etc). Producing results in vector format would be great if possible too.

**Update:**
Rather than just recreating with ASCII-art, I'd like to also specify the string which is used to recreate the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite simple: divide the image with a grid, compute average color (or luminosity or hue, etc.) of the pixels found on each grid cell, create an image of same size, draw the letter corresponding to the grid cell with the found color.

Comment: That would be assuming a fixed-width font?

Comment: If you're being adventurous, you could also weight different characters be the amount of space they take up when printed (So you might make 'i' artificially lighter than 'I' to achieve the same luminosity in the result)

Comment: @Phillip: yes, the simple solution (used in the question itself too) requires a fixed-width font

Comment: @Phillip: I posted the second answer before seeing your comment... As I wrote, a fixed font gives better results, but since I position each char individually, a proportional font is OK. Can play with dingbat fonts too...

Answer (score 2):

I was a bit buzzy, but I finally hacked a little [Processing](http://Processing.org) sketch to demonstrate my algorithm.

```
final int GRID_SIZE_H = 9;
final int GRID_SIZE_V = 9;
final int GRID_SIZE = GRID_SIZE_H * GRID_SIZE_V;
final String TEXT_TO_DISPLAY = "Picture yourself in a boat on a river With tangerine trees and marmalade skies";

void setup()
{
  size(600, 600);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
  background(0);

  PImage niceImage = loadImage("SomeImage.png");
  int niW  = niceImage.width;
  int niH = niceImage.height;
  int imgW = niW + 10;
  image(niceImage, 0, 0);

  PFont f = loadFont("Arial-Black-12.vlw");
  textFont(f);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  String textToDisplay = TEXT_TO_DISPLAY.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\s", "");

  int pos = 0;
  niceImage.loadPixels();
  for (int j = 0; j < niH - GRID_SIZE_V; j += GRID_SIZE_V)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < niW - GRID_SIZE_H; i += GRID_SIZE_H)
    {
      long avgR = 0, avgG = 0, avgB = 0;
      for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE_H; x++)
      {
        for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE_V; y++)
        {
          int c = niceImage.pixels[i + x + (j + y) * niW];
          avgR += (c >> 16) & 0xFF;
          avgG += (c >>  8) & 0xFF;
          avgB +=  c        & 0xFF;
        }
      }
      color clr = color(avgR / GRID_SIZE, avgG / GRID_SIZE, avgB / GRID_SIZE);
      fill(clr);
      char chr = textToDisplay.charAt(pos++);
      pos = pos % textToDisplay.length();
      text(chr, i + imgW, j + 12);
    }
  }
}
```

Should work better with a fat (bold) monospaced font.

Answer (score 0):

There are two drivers for mplayer that address this, one is BW called "libaa" / ascii-art, the other "libcaca":

Sources are available to both, I don't remember under which license.

See this for screenshots of both libs in action:
http://liquidweather.net/howto/index.php?id=74

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler than PhiLho's answer. Just render the text to an image of the same size in all white on black background (this could be pre-generated if you like) and multiply this "text mask" image with your source image. Blurring the source image with a gaussian blur whose radius is comparable to the text size might be desirable if you don't want smaller-than-character detail to remain visible.